# Largest rectangle inside a square

Tags: geometry, area

For e.g I have rectangle with known sides and a square with a known side as well.
I would like to know if this rectangle can be inscribed or just can "pass through" the square.
I understand that area of rectangle should be lesser or equal. 
But there is also a case when I rotate the rectangle with some side greater, than square side and rectangle will pass.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a rectangle $ABDC$ of side $2b \times 2a$, placed with center
at the origin, like in the sketch.

[image]

Then consider a square, sides $2s \times 2s$, also placed
with the center at the origin, having one corner at $P=(s,s)$.

It is clear that the minimum square through which the rectangle
is still "passing through" would be the one for which
 -  the segment $AB$ is contained in the square, or
 -  the segment $A'B'$ ($AB$ rotated by $45^\circ$) is contained in the square
which can be seen by considering to gradually rotate the segment along the circumscribing circle.

In the second case, shifting back the triangle $P'A'B'$ to $PAB$, noting that the angle in $P$ is $90^\circ$, then we will have 
$$|PH| =a$$
and thus
$$|PH|+|HO| =a+b= \sqrt{2}\,s$$

So, to pass we shall have
$$
a \le b \le s\quad  \vee \quad {{a + b} \over {\sqrt 2 }} \le s
$$

At this point we can scale by a factor 2 and tell the inequalities above are for a rectangle of sides $a,b$ and a square of side $s$

Answer (score 0):

As usual, you should draw a picture, like below.  Let the short side of the rectangle be $a$, the long side $b$, and the side of the square be $s$.  To fit horizontally we need $a\cos (\frac \pi 2-\theta)+b\cos \theta =a\sin \theta + b \cos \theta \le s$.  Similarly, to fit vertically we need $a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta \le s$

[image]

For a given $a,b$ you can find the minimum $s$ and proper $\theta$ by setting these equal.  $$s=a\cos \theta+b\sin \theta=a\sin \theta + b\cos \theta\\
a+\frac b{\tan \theta}=a\tan \theta + b$$  This is a quadratic in $\tan \theta$

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but how can I count the angle θ?

Comment: See the edit...

Answer (score 0):

[Length of square is a+b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxTvP.jpg)

I made this answer because I think the other two answers are more complex than they need to be. The OP asks "I would like to know if this rectangle can be inscribed or just can "pass through" the square". Here I am calculating the smallest square that the rectangle will pass through. If that square is less than or equal to the proposed square then the answer is 'yes'.

Since the outside constraining shape is a square and the inside shape is a rectangle (90 degree corners, unlike Ross's diagram), the optimum angle of the inside shape must necessarily be 45 degrees or 90 degrees. For 90 degree the comparison is trivial, the largest side of the rectangle must be less than or equal to the size of the square.

For 45 degree orientation, the smallest square that the rectangle fits through is (refer to the diagram in the link above):

For rectangle long side x and rectangle short side y, the length of the smallest square s is a+b.

$$\sin 45 = \frac{a}{x}$$
$$\cos 45 = \frac{y/2}{b}$$

So,

$$a = x \sin 45$$
$$b = \frac{y/2}{\cos 45}$$

$$s = a + b$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).